# Check whether forward-sexp was successful in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, emacs24

I would like to check whether a `(forward-sexp 1)` was succesful, or ended with an error. 
The problem is that it returns nil, even when it has been successful. How to do this check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `scan-sexps` instead.
It is the workhorse behind `forward-sexp` and returns a meaningful value.

Of course, if the parens are not balanced, then you will get an error - so you will need `ignore-errors` or `condition-case`.

Answer (score 5):

`forward-sexp` signals an error if it cannot move the point forward.  You can catch this with `condition-case` if you want.  Here is an example command testing it:

```
(defun test-forward-sexp ()
  "simple command testing (forward-sexp 1)"
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil
      (progn
        (forward-sexp 1)
        (message "succeeded"))
    (error (message "failed"))))
```

You can read more about handling errors on the info page [Writing Code to Handle Errors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html).

Comment: It is not a direct answer to the question, but I notice that this is indeed the underlying answer, probably even more appropriately addressing what really should be done in this case (the use of `condition-case`, that is)!

Comment: @Dualinity I think you misunderstood your question.

Comment: I don't think I am misunderstanding now. I forgot to include ignore-errors in the question, which might lead there to be confusion. The answer now adequately solves the `(forward-sexp)` giving a nil problem: scan gives a value if it works, while forward-sexp gives nil when it works. Your way, is a more general method for how tests for error should be done. They are different questions? A direct answer is to use `scan-sexps` (to avoid the nil), the indirect answer is to more appropriately deal when there is an error, which would also solve this problem?

Comment: @Dualinity Read your question literally, you ask how use `forward-sexp` and detect errors - not how to write code to move over sexps.  I think the accepted answer is great.  I only object to your comment that my answer wasn't a direct answer to the question.

Comment: Granted, reading literally becomes difficult when being involved with the matter :-). My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

`forward-sexp` doesn't return nil if there's an error (it doesn't return anything, in fact in that case; it signals an error instead).

Comment: I agree, but given that we are trying to get a `t` or a `nil` return, we can obtain `nil` in an error case by using `(ignore-errors FUN)`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then you can get what you want with `(ignore-errors (forward-sexp 1) t)`.